# R: Problem with time AM/PM values when trying to convert them to 24h

Tags: r, datetime, type-conversion

I have a dataframe, called "dataall" which has, among others, a column "Times" of time values with AM/PM indication, with class character:

```
dataall$Time[1:10]  
[1] "12:50 AM" "1:50 AM"  "2:50 AM"  "3:50 AM"  "5:20 AM"  
[6] "5:50 AM"  "6:20 AM"  "6:50 AM"  "7:20 AM"  "7:50 AM"
```

I want to have the data in a 24h format.
After reading some posts, I did the following attempts:

1:
dataall$time24h <- as.POSIXct(dataall$Time, format='%I:%M %p')

2: 
dataall$time24h <- format(strptime(dataall$Time, "%I:%M %p"), format="%H:%M")

But I am receiving NAs

Comment: Your example is working fine for me `format(strptime(v1, format = "%I:%M %p"), format="%H:%M")
 [1] "00:50" "01:50" "02:50" "03:50" "05:20" "05:50" "06:20" "06:50" "07:20" "07:50"` where `v1 <- c("12:50 AM", "1:50 AM", "2:50 AM", "3:50 AM", "5:20 AM", "5:50 AM", 
"6:20 AM", "6:50 AM", "7:20 AM", "7:50 AM")`

Comment: I am receiving:  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

Comment: okay, it must be some locale setting issuess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the `parse_date_time` function in the lubridate package

```
v1 <- c("12:50 AM", "1:50 AM", "2:50 AM", "3:50 AM", "5:20 AM", "5:50 AM", "6:20 AM", "6:50 AM", "7:20 AM", "7:50 AM", "7:50 PM")
x <- lubridate::parse_date_time(v1,'H:M p')
format(x, format = '%H:%M')

#[1] "00:50" "01:50" "02:50" "03:50" "05:20" "05:50" "06:20" "06:50" "07:20" "07:50" "19:50"
```

If there is a locale problem, have a look at the help for `parse_date_time` for some suggestions.